# How to process array data in chunks where last chunk may be a partial size

Tags: c, esp32, arduino-ide

I have array of integer and I am trying to send this array as a sub block from esp32 to another one.
According this code I get on output like this:

**output:**
1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10

11 12 0 0 0

**the expected output:**

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10

11 12

How can I update on esp_now_send to get like the expected output? how can I deal with the last sub block if it is less than 5 numbers?

Comment: You need to pad the `data` to ensure it has complete sub-blocks. Otherwise the last iteration will overflow the array. Or you need to ensure the last send is the right size to deal with an incomplete sub-block and not just `range` all the time.

Comment: Yes, I am asking about that how can I deal with the last sub block if it is less than 5 numbers?

Comment: Well suppose you had 12 oranges to pass to a relative five at a time and the relative didn't know to expect only 12, how would you deal with that?

Comment: Change `siz` to be the real number of entries in the array: `size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])`. Then change `rang` in the function call to `(ind + rang <= size ? rang : size - ind)`. That is, the size passed to the function call depends on how much data is left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs to send up to only the available data. To do that the general approach would be to send full sub-blocks until the last sub-block which may be a partial one. That can be determined by simple maths logic to work out how much the current iteration should send based on how much data is left.

The code changes would be:

1. Change `siz` to be the real number of entries in the array: `siz = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]).`
2. Change `rang` in the function call to `(ind + rang <= size ? rang : size - ind)``. That is, the size passed to the function call depends on how much data is left.

Comment: I need your help please, could you see the updated code? why when use rang =5; this code did not sent all the values?

Comment: @oleva Please do not update the post/code with significant changes after it has already been answered. Please revert the changes and post a new question describing the new issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that now.